# Multi search form in orchard cms

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am developing a site with Orchard CMS that has three functions. The site has one global search form that search all of content by type (I used the search form widget).

One site has an "Article" content type. I had created a page to display all of articles.

**How do I create other search forms in this article page that search only by the article's content type?**

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post by an old developer I used to work with, explains how to create an advanced search form.

http://breakoutdeveloper.com/orchard-cms/creating-an-advanced-search

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Can you help me solve this proplems??? I need two search form in site but search widget (only choice one indexer) in orchard cms can't do. thanks

see below link for detail: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hdRAO.jpg